# Trying to dynamically add, and name, div to page using javascript/php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am new to php and javascript.  I want to dynamically add a div to a page with php.  In the end what I want is to be able to call a php function that adds a div.  I want to call the function multiple times for a single page - so I want to add multiple divs via multiple function calls.

That doesn't seem to be difficult, but... I want each of the dynamically added divs to have the same class name, but a unique id and, for various reasons, I want the id to be based on the number of divs of that class already on the page (e.g. the first div added might have id = 0. the second id = 1, third id = 2 etc.).

I have looked a stackoverflow but haven't found any clues.  I'd really appreciate any help.

I have tried the following, but it doesn't work (this is a very simplified version):

```
function getCount() {
    ?><script>
        $(document).ready(function(){

            var elems = $('body').find('.mydiv');

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '',
                data: {count: elems.length},                
                cache: false,
                success: function(response) {  
                    console.log(response);
                }
            });
        });
    </script><?
}



echo '<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Test</title>
            <script src="../jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
        </head>

        <body>';

        $count = -1;

        getCount();

        if (!empty($_POST)) {
            foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
                if (!empty($key) && !empty($value)) {
                    echo 'key = '.$key.'  value = '.$value;
                    if ($key == 'count') {
                        $count = $value;
                    }
                }               
            }
        }           

        if ($count > -1)
            echo "<div class = 'mydiv' id = 'mydiv".$count."'></div>";

echo "</body></html>";
```

Comment: Does your server (PHP) need to know how many divs there are? Or can you add them on the client side via JavaScript/jQuery? The latter would be much easier, you wouldn't need AJAX.

Comment: The sever needs to know.

Answer (score 0):

you dont want to mix js and php here, you can achieve this using php alone, here is the code sample

```
<?php
echo 'your headers and layout tags go here';

function addDiv($count){
echo "<div class = 'mydiv' id = 'mydiv".$count."'>current div id is ".$count."</div>";
}
$count=0;
addDiv($count++);
addDiv($count++);
addDiv($count++);

?>
```

Comment: That doesn't work for me.  The caller of the addDiv function can't provide the count (or the seed).